# Add `\x on` to PostgresDB query with kubectl exec

Tags: postgresql, psql, kubectl

I have a PostgresDB query which I want to run directly using `kubectl exec`:

```
kubectl exec -it -n <ns> <pod_name> -- psql -U <user> -d <db> -c "select * from <table> where id=1234;"
```

I want to toggle expanded output (`\x on` option) only for this command.  I do not want to permanently enable this for all queries.

I have tried various things, such as chaining commands together with a semi-colon (i.e. `\x on; select * from <table>;`).  I'm not getting this to work.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: You can add `-P expanded=on` to the command line options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do that, but the simplest is to use the `-x` option of `psql`.